# Thread count increases with running logger.info in greenlet

Tags: python, logging, gevent

With the following code if I uncomment `log_it`, `threading.active_count` reaches 11. 
Since It means each logger creates `_DummyThread daemons.Now`

Q1.Is their any way to achieve the same without creating extra threads?

Q2.Why logger needs to create another thread.Why can't it execute in same way, like `fun` function?

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import threading
import gc
import gevent
import logging

def print_stats():
    while True:
        gc.collect()
        print threading.active_count() 
        gevent.sleep(2)

jobs = [gevent.spawn(print_stats)]
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
form = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(form)
logger.addHandler(ch)

def log_it():
    string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    logger.info(string)

def fun():
    print "hello world"

def block_for_some_time():
    log_it()
    fun()
    gevent.sleep(5)
    print 'exiting thread'

for i in range(10):
    jobs.append(gevent.spawn(block_for_some_time))

gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change pathcing to this:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
```

`threading.active_count()` will print 1 all times. The reason is in patching threading module, 
 that provides you with information about "greenlets", not about real threads.